# Chrome not opening links in web push notifications

Tags: google-chrome, web-push

We've implemented web push notifications for Chrome following the guidelines from [1][2][3]. The system is in production and extensively tested by our userbase but we've received some reports that some URLs are not opened by Google Chrome.

We think that this is happening only to a small portion of our users which are using Windows 10 and Google Chrome +74. And this is not happening on every link they receive. Sometimes they're able to open those links but sometimes they can't. That makes it even stranger and more difficult to reproduce and fix.

The code we used is heavily inspired by the implementations provided by the aforementioned links.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Thanks!

[1] https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/

[2] https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web

[3] https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this may be related to a bug I reported to Chromium for Chrome / Windows 10 displaying multiple notifications from different origins at one time.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=890343

For example, this can happen when the browser is initially started (on login, etc.) and there are multiple notifications pending. The "unclickable" notifications often correspond to an "Updated in the background" notification which should only occur when the promise chain of the [notification event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NotificationEvent) does not resolve as expected or within the required interval.

Does this sound like the behavior you have noticed? If so, please try to reproduce the bug using the steps described and/or star the issue. The steps are based on a gauntface fork (a contributor you referenced [3]).

Comment: Hi Mitchell thanks for your information. This is happening every time we receive and open a push notification from a source. 

I've seen those "updated in the background" notifications but we're not in that case. If we send the notification two other users, thay can click on them but there are some particular users that click on them and Chrome won't open the link.

Comment: I found this solution.  Setting "Enable Native Notifications" as "disabled" works but the formatting of the notification is using the old styled version. https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/3210517?hl=en